# why get in query is empty and not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

Hello What is my code problem it's not working i tested by another address like : http://arasadr.ir/temp/index.php .

in this code i get a var like 12,11 , and i don't see any alert.

http://192.168.4.1/data : Not Work

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test.asp : Work

http://arasadr.ir/temp/index.php : Not Work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = "http://192.168.4.1/data";
    $.get(url, function(data, status){
      alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: `<script src="/Jquery.js"></script>`, this should be like `<script src="./Jquery.js"></script>`, if the file is in the root, right ?

Comment: @AkhilAravind not necessarily.

Comment: What debugging attempts have you made? Do you see the alerts? What data does your server receive? Have you checked for errors in the console? Have you checked the state of the request in dev tools?

Comment: Generally, *by default* you can only issue a request back up to the same server from which the HTML was loaded. if the HTML was loaded from someplace other than `192.168.4.1`, then this is an AJAX cross domain request. Check your browser console to see what the actual error is.

Comment: a don't see any alert some , server don't receive data some  get working in some urls  like https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test.asp but in http://arasadr.ir/temp/index.php or http://192.168.4.1/data not work .

Comment: You need to the check the browser's network tab.  Where exactly are you testing this from? `192.168.4.1` is a local network address so may not work outside your local network.  All the other information in the question (the arrays, then graph) appear to be superfluous to the question.

Comment: sorry yes that was superfluous i edited questions thanks . 192.168.4.1 is in local but  arasadr.ir/temp/index.php is not .

Answer (score 0):

i found that i must turn on VPN .
thanks every one .